# in a server ubuntu 16.04 pointing all sub-domain to domain

Tags: apache2, webserver, hosts

site1.conf

[image]

all domain point to one site

```
<VirtualHost dev.site1.com:80>  
    ServerName dev.site1.com  
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site1  
</VirtualHost>


site2.conf
<VirtualHost dev.site2.com:80>
    ServerName dev.site2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site2
</VirtualHost>


site3.conf
<VirtualHost dev.site3.com:80>
    ServerName dev.site3.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site3
</VirtualHost>
```

where i missing

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Your question (and setup) is not very clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it's really hard to understand what you would like to know.
Let me guess … You would like to make 3 different domains available under one IP on an Apache web server. Right?

Solution:

- Don't put the domain names in the `<VirtualHost …>` line. This line is meant to hold the server's public IP address.
- Maybe only a minor issues but put the DocumentRoot path in quotes ""

Your config should propably look like this:

(replace IP, DocumentRoot and ServerName with your own values, of course)

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost 172.20.30.40>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example1"
    ServerName www.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 172.20.30.40>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example2"
    ServerName www.example.org
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 172.20.30.40>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example3"
    ServerName www.example.net
</VirtualHost>
```

Source: [Apache VirtualHost Examples](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html)